# MongoDB Query on table with array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have the following table DBLIST, and how do i write the equivalent to this query on this table

```
select databases.name,databases.host,databases.ha_map from DBLIST where "id"="DB1" and databases.dbrole="Primary";

DBLIST
{
  "_id": "DB1",
  "databases": [
    {
      "type": "Production",
      "name": "Prim1",
      "dbversion":"12.1.0.2.0",
      "host": "Host1",
      "dbrole": "Primary",
      "ha_map":"Stdby1"
    },
    {
      "type": "Production",
      "name": "Stdby1",
       "dbversion":"12.1.0.2.0",
      "host": "host2",
      "dbrole": "Standby",
      "ha_map":"Prim1"
    }
  ],
  "pdba": "First Name ",
  "sdba": "Last Name",
  "application": "Sample Project",
  "owner": "Last Name"
}
```

Want to get the result like,(key :value ) is fine, does not have to be tabular.

id,databaases.name,databases.host,databases.ha_map
DB1,Prim1,Host1,Stdby1

Comment: Hey James, Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the step by step demonstration of what you want.

Let's assume that, we have this entry in our collection `dblist`.

```
{
  "_id": "DB1",
  "databases": [
    {
      "type": "Production",
      "name": "Prim1",
      "dbversion":"12.1.0.2.0",
      "host": "Host1",
      "dbrole": "Primary",
      "ha_map":"Stdby1"
    },
    {
      "type": "Production",
      "name": "Stdby1",
       "dbversion":"12.1.0.2.0",
      "host": "host2",
      "dbrole": "Standby",
      "ha_map":"Prim1"
    }
  ],
  "pdba": "First Name ",
  "sdba": "Last Name",
  "application": "Sample Project",
  "owner": "Last Name"
}
```

---

**STEP 1**

Now if we want to find this element among a set of documents, we can query,

```
db.dblist.findOne({ _id: "DB1" });
```

This query will output the above whole document.

**STEP 2**

Within the same document, we have 2 entries for `databases`, in that we want to find the subdocument, `dbrole: "Primary".

```
db.dblist.findOne({ _id: "DB1", "databases.dbrole": "Primary" });
```

or we can also use, `elemMatch`

```
db.dblist.findOne({ _id: "DB1" }, { databases: { $elemMatch: { dbrole: "Primary"} } });
```

Now again it outputs the same document as we are querying the document.

**STEP 3**

Now we want to retrieve a subdocument out of it, which is databases and its matching `name`, `host`, `ha_map`.

```
db.dblist.findOne({ _id: "DB1" }, { databases: { $elemMatch: { dbrole: "Primary"}, "databases.name": 1, "databases.host": 1, "databases.ha_map": 1, _id: 0 } });
```

Now the output of this query will be,

```
{
  "databases": [
    {
      "name": "Prim1",
      "host": "Host1",
      "ha_map": "Stdby1"
    }
}
```

which I hope is what you want!

---

So the final query to obtain the output is,

```
db.dblist.findOne({ _id: "DB1" }, { databases: { $elemMatch: { dbrole: "Primary"}, "databases.name": 1, "databases.host": 1, "databases.ha_map": 1, _id: 0 } });
```

---

Hope this helps!